# Simplifying a expression using factorization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

can anyone explain me how can I solved this problem ?

"Use factorization to simplify this expression:"

$\ \left( 6\over m+3 \right)^{-1}  \left( 6 m^{2}-15 m-9 \over 2m^{2} -18 \right)^{-1} $

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Start factorizing $6m^2-15m-9$ using the formula for the quadratic equation. Do the same with $2m^2-18$ which "looks" like $a^2-b^2$

Comment: Thanks, Claude!

Answer (score 1):

hint:$$\ \left( 6\over m+3 \right)^{-1}  \left( 6 m^{2}-15 m-9 \over 2m^{2} -18 \right)^{-1}=\\
\left( m+3\over 6 \right)  \left(  2m^2-18\over 6 m^{2}-15 m-9\right)=\\
\ \left( m+3\over 6 \right)  \left(  2(m^2-9)\over 3(2 m^{2}-5 m-3)\right)=\\
\left( m+3\over 6 \right)  \left(  2(m^2-9)\over 3(2 m^{2}-5 m-3)\right)=\\\frac{2}{6\times 3}(m+3)  \left(  (m^2-9)\over (2 m^{2}-5 m-3)\right)=\\
\frac{1}{3\times 3}(m+3)  \left(  (m-3)(m+3)\over (2m+1)(m-3)\right)=\\
\frac{1}{3\times 3}(m+3)  \left(  \not{(m-3)}(m+3)\over (2m+1)\not(m-3)\right)=\\$$

Comment: Thanks Khosrotash!

Comment: why you are inverting the fractions ?, it's for eliminate the exponents -1 ?

Comment: @AlgBaldor:of course

Comment: I cannot solve this problem, can you explain a little more the operations ?

Comment: I don't understand why the fraction: 2/6.3 , and I don't know how continue with the operations.